# Differentiate $f(x)=\frac{2-x^2}{3x+x^2}$

Tags: calculus

I am double checking a question I was given on a test that was marked wrong and I am not sure how I got it wrong.

Find $f'(x)$:$$\begin{align*} f(x) &=\dfrac{2-x^2}{3x+x^2}\\
f'(x) &=\dfrac{(2x)(3x+x^2)-(2-x^2)(3+2x)}{(3x+x^2)^2}\\
f'(x) &=\dfrac{3x^2+4x-6}{(3x+x^2)^2} \end{align*}$$

However on the test he marked a negative sign out on the second step on the $2x$.  Would anyone mind explaining where I went wrong?

Comment: isn't to be -2x ?

Comment: typo in your title. It is spelled derriere.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha is a great tool for checking these kinds of calculations: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D[+%282-x^2%29%2F%283x%2Bx^2%29%2C+x]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the quotient rule, the derivative is

\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= \frac{(3x + x^2) \frac{d}{dx}(2 - x^2) - (2 - x^2)\frac{d}{dx}(3x + x^2)'}{(3x + x^2)^2} \\
\end{align*}

The derivative of $2 - x^2$ is $-2x$. Everything else seems correct.

Comment: ah, dumb mistake forgot to carry over the sign. Thanks